# how can redirect domain to https except internal IP (192.168.1.10) in IIS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

for example :
URL : http://test.com or [www.test.com](http://www.test.com)
redirect to https://test.com

but URL is : 192.168.1.10
open 192.168.1.10

in IIS rewrite URL

Comment: Learn to use conditions in your rules, such as Mistake 1 in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0):

You can negate a pattern using the `negate` attribute of the  element. when using this property, the rule action will only be performed if the current URL does not match the specified pattern. Here are the rules you can use as a reference:

```
<rule name="test" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="192.168.1.10" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```